# Trying To Grab QuerySet Info

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Iam working with Django/Python/Mezzanine and trying to access the category field

so when I grab the article via

```
todays_articles  = BlogPost.objects.get(id=1)
```

and then do a

```
todays_articles.categories.all()
```

I get this  [BlogCategory: news]

How do I extract only the "news" part of it.  Thanks

Comment: Can you show your models? Is 'news' a field in a Category model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [src](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/_modules/mezzanine/blog/models.html#BlogCategory) mentions `title` as an ordering option so I would try pulling that out in a comprehension:
`[category.title for category in todays_articles.categories.all()]`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like:

```
result = todays_articles.categories.values_list('title', flat=True)
```